# /var/log/messages Not Created Although restart rsyslog.service

Tags: linux, logging, centos7, syslog, rsyslog

I use centos7 and `/var/log/messages` has not worked for a while although I restarted `rsyslog.service`.  Its size was always 0.

I then deleted the messages file, and restarted `rsyslog` again but it was not created automatically.

I can not log anything currently.  What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

centos7 is `systemd` based system, and logging is ensured with `systemd-journald` daemon.

you can display logs using command `journalctl -r`.

many options are available in the `man journalctl` manpage

Answer (score 0):

This command would show all files open with `rsyslogd`. It should show `/var/log/messages`.

`lsof -p $(pgrep rsyslogd)`

If you don't see the file in the output, `rsyslog` might not be using it at all. So check your `rsyslog` configuration `/etc/rsyslog.conf`. It should show a line like this in a default Centos 7 install:

```
*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none                /var/log/messages
```

Answer (score 0):

For **rsyslog** you have to first check the /etc/rsyslog.conf configuration file entries if your messages files is not in the /var/log/ directory:

```
 *.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none /var/log/messages
```

To display kernel related logs you can use journalctl command like this:

```
journalctl -k
```